# How can I detect press on background?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to detect press on background (not on items inside FlatList) of FlatList? How?

What I tried:

- onPress prop did not work (as expected since it is not documented).
- Wrapping FlatList inside TouchableHighlight element did not trigger.

Answer (score 1):

If your Flatlist is inside a View you can use this method:

```
<View
    onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) => true}
    onResponderGrant={(evt) => {

        this.handlePress(evt.nativeEvent)
    }}
>
```

Then you have to handle the differents events.

the event object contains many variables you can use.

exemple:

```
handlePress(event){
    console.log('x = ' + event.pageX)
    console.log('y = ' + event.pageY)
}
```

doc: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll experiment with this... this at least eliminates the extra View that I added on top of the FlatList as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible as there is no method that could be used for it connected to FlatList. A full list of the methods can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listemptycomponent
However, if you need to add some functionality to your flatlist that is not connected to it's items the onRefresh function does a great job. It is triggered when you "overscroll" the list and works for flatlist with regular orientation as well as reversed!
Paste this into your flatlist and write the method:

```
refreshControl={
             <RefreshControl
              refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
             />}
```

Comment: I solved it myself by calculating the empty background height and place a TouchableHighlight on top of the FlatList... Yes, dirty... but it works!